# Parsing JSON surrounded by HTML tags

Tags: objective-c, json

Taking up iOS again from the start. And now recalling why I quit last time. Anyway, here's my problem. Please help me figure out the issue. Please don't point to other links on SO. I've *almost literally* gone through all PHP-JSON-Objective C questions on here. Also, NO FRAMEWORKS please.

Here's the php:

```
header('content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Here's the output:

```
<html>
<body>

{"loginstatus":"0"}

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the objective-c code:

```
NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:oResponseData options:kNilOptions error:&errorInfo];

if (parsedJSON == nil) {
    NSLog(@"not created");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [errorInfo userInfo]);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
2013-08-11 16:08:38.734 TestProject [32516:c07] not created
2013-08-11 16:08:38.736 TestProject [32516:c07] Error: { NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the html tags.

This must be the only output:

```
{"loginstatus":"0"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Deleted my other response as I realized that was not the correct way to do it. Don't want to add confusion for others. I'm yet to figure out why I'm getting the HTML tags though. I'm not using any tempting library. Pure PHP.

Comment: So did you tried the `exit;`? This should immediately terminate your script and prevent all other output.

Comment: exit didn't fix the issue but helped me figure out why I was getting those tags. Some time back while creating the service itself, before and after <?php ... ?>, I had added <html> tags. Embarrassing. I was butting head at the wrong place. Should have checked my service code first instead of trying to "fix" the app code. Thanks for your help.